# restful service for different clients

Tags: java, rest, mobile, desktop

I have a back-end restful service and want to use it for 2 different clients(Desktop and mobile) with different responses. Do we need create 2 different APIs for this ? How will we know where the request is originating from?

Comment: Maybe better suited for [Software Engineering](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/), but just describe your case... Why do you need different responses? Different data or different content type?

Comment: I was asked this in interview. He want list of countries to be less for mobile client compared to desktop client

Answer (score 0):

Take "device-type" as one of the param and return a JSON to the client.

Client should be responsible to send proper "device-type" as param. For client it would be easy to identify "device-type", as client resides on device.

or You can have two APIs one for each device.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the same API for both clients. You can find out which client the API is coming from by checking the "User-Agent" field which comes as a request header.

Comment: REST API are consumed by programmatic clients that typically don't set a user agent by default.  Check [Does it make sense for User-Agent to be required for REST APIs?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/355670/does-it-make-sense-for-user-agent-to-be-required-for-rest-apis)

Answer (score 0):

Two cookies can be helpful for identifying client: "User-Agent" and "Referer". I will suggest to keep the APIs separate as you may want to maintain versions going forward. Also if the responses are different having the same endpoint means you will have some if-else somewhere to figure out where the request is coming from. Like we have say different urls for desktop and mobile like `xyz.com` and `m.xyz.com`; you can have similar apis or `domain.com/m/v1/api` whatever suits you